# Cual es la ventaja de agregar indices en las tablas en SQL

Tags: sql, indices

Hola a tod@s en StackOverflow!! Espero esten bien.

En relacion a mi consulta, agradeceria saber cual es la ventaja de emplear Indices-tengo entendido puedo tener hasta 250 por tabla-en mis tablas de SQL y si existen casos en los que definitivamente deben emplearse.

Agradeciendo sus comentarios para poder enriquecer el diseño y administracion de mis bases de datos.

Gabriela

Comment: Hay libros enteros explicando las ventajas y posibles desventajas en crear índices....es un tópico extremadamente extenso para poder ser abordado en una pregunta en SO. Si quieres pensarlo de forma muy muy simple, la ventaja de un índice en una tabla es la misma a la de un índice en un libro...te indica en forma rápida dónde está el dato que quieres. La desventaja es que hay que mantener los índices...si agregas más datos (o borras o cambias), el índice también debe cambiar. (ojo que esto es una explicación en extremo superficial)

Comment: Y para futuras referencias.. Sql es un lenguaje de consultas a base de datos. Cuando necesites preguntar sobre alguna en particular, se explicito.

Comment: Gracias a todos por sus comentarios!! Considerare sus recomendaciones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La principal ventaja de los índices es que las búsquedas serán más rápidas, ya que evita la sobrecarga de la CPU y de disco. Sin embargo no es recomendable dejar tantos índices en una tabla debido a que las funciones de escritura pueden ralentizarse, además de que ocuparás más espacio.

Ten en cuenta esto antes de usar índices:

> - Cualquier índice, ya sea bueno o malo, incrementa el tiempo de operaciones INSERT/UPDATE
> - Aplicar un índice solo a aquellas columnas usadas en cláusulas WHERE y ORDER BY. Crear índices en exceso resultará en bajo rendimiento de las consultas.
> - Usar la restricción NOT NULL en las columnas que se van a indizar, para evitar que se almacenen valores nulos.

Esto sumado a una buena normalización permitirá un buen rendimiento de tu BD.

Comment: Los valores nulos no se indexan (en la gran mayoria de las bases de datos). solo se incrementan los tiempos de update si efectivamente se tocan columnas de los indices (cosa rara, porque esas columnas "suelen" ser claves para las tablas). Si sabes de antemano todos los where que vas a necesitar, sos mago realmente ;)... Todo lo que decis es valido, siempre y cuando veas el contexto.. por eso hay escrito libros enteros sobre esto.

Comment: El problema es que no se puede hablar de "siempre"....todo tiene excepciones. Por ejemplo "Cualquier índice, ya sea bueno o malo, incrementa el tiempo de operaciones INSERT/UPDATE" no necesariamente sucede; es lo más probable, pero un `UPDATE` puede ayudarse de un índice para encontrar las filas que quieres actualizar, y ese costo puede ser menor al de mantener el índice una vez actualizado el dato

Comment: Gracias por sus respuestas!! Me han ayudado a entender mas como puedo emplear los indices